# Ruby: How to remove trailing backslashes from a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, postgresql

I have a string like

```
"car\"
```

which I will be storing in postgres db. I want to remove the backslash from the string before saving. Is there a way I can do that in ruby or in postgres? When I try to remove it in ruby, it considers the quote after the backslash as an escape character.

Comment: You have to double the backslash in your search string.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

See following code:

```
1.9.3p125 :022 > s = "cat\\"
 => "cat\\" 
1.9.3p125 :023 > puts s
cat\
 => nil 
1.9.3p125 :024 > s.chomp("\\")
 => "cat" 
1.9.3p125 :025 >
```

Comment: Ruby's chomp method was designed for this purpose. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-chomp

Answer (score 2):

To remove a trailing backslash:

```
"car\\".gsub!(/\\$/, "")
```

Note that the backslash has to be escaped itself with a backslash.

Answer (score 2):

People don't do this much, but Ruby's String class supports:

```
irb(main):002:0> str = 'car\\'
=> "car\\"
irb(main):003:0> str[/\\$/] = ''
=> ""
irb(main):004:0> str
=> "car"
```

It's a conditional search for a trailing '\', and replacement with an empty string.

Comment: The problem is my rails app receives a single trailing backslash from the frontend (mistakenly by a user) which I need to store in the database. Any clues on how to deal with such a situation?

Comment: That's what the example is demonstrating. A single trailing backslash. 'car\\' creates a string containing a single trailing backslash. The final line shows that the single trailing back-slash is removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
puts '"car\"'.gsub(/\\(")?$/, '\1')
```

that will do it,
but, is the trailing slash always at the en followed by a quote?

Comment: `/\\(")*$/` is a very awkward way of handling a possible trailing quote, and actually means "zero or more" trailing quotes.

Answer (score -3):

See what says the

```
str.dump
```

operation, and then try to operate on that.

Comment: What will happen if the string *doesn't* have a trailing back-slash?

Comment: Sure, we would need to know how this string looks like in detail, when it comes to ruby? "\"car\\", "\"car\\\""?

Comment: @theTinMan in the documentation it says that nil will be returned

```returning str, or nil if no substitutions were performed. If no block and no replacement is given, an enumerator is returned instead.```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html

Comment: You're late to the party. The original answer used `str.chop` and was changed to `str.dump` shortly after I asked my question. My comment was directed at the use of `chop` which failed the OPs requirements.  Neither is documented with what you said.